# Error: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, erc-721

I have a deployed contract. Now I want to make changes through the Remix, but there was some kind of error. please help me to solve this error. thanks.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol"; 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

Error: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. -->

I tried changing compiler but it didn't help

[image]

**SOURCE:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract World_Tanks is ERC721A, Ownable {

    struct TokenInfo {
        IERC20 paytoken;
        uint256 costvalue;
    }

    TokenInfo[] public AllowedCrypto;
    
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10150;
    string public baseURI = "ipfs://QmUb6V6CzKKZ5Z5ihjU1pzM8PhZH5zMVMVuaNgFMWvpT4e/";
    constructor() ERC721A("World_Tanks", "WTS"){_safeMint(owner(), 1000);}   
    
    function addCurrency(
        IERC20 _paytoken,
        uint256 _costvalue
    ) public onlyOwner {
        AllowedCrypto.push(
            TokenInfo({
                paytoken: _paytoken,
                costvalue: _costvalue
            })
        );
    }

    function mint(uint amount) external payable {
        TokenInfo storage tokens = AllowedCrypto[_pid];
        IERC20 paytoken;
        paytoken = tokens.paytoken;
        uint256 cost;
        cost = tokens.costvalue;
        require(totalSupply() +amount <= maxSupply, "maxSupply reached");
        require(msg.value >= cost*amount, "not enough ether sent");
        _safeMint(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory a) external onlyOwner {
        baseURI = a; 
    }

    function setCost(uint256 a) external onlyOwner {
        cost = a;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) override public view returns(string memory) {
        return(string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, Strings.toString(tokenId+1), ".json")));
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you imported the Strings.sol library from OpenZeppelin?

Comment: I did this and two new errors appeared: 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
**
    DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contracts/Worldtanktest.sol:35:50:
|
35 | TokenInfo storage tokens = AllowedCrypto[_pid];
| ^^^^

**

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contracts/Worldtanktest.sol:58:9:
|
58 | cost = a;
| ^^^^

Comment: i have pasted the full code in the question

Comment: Hello Gencho, as Ismael said you did not import suitable libraries but after improving your import section you have another problem. I recommended to do changes and editing your code for a better help

Comment: the problem was solved after adding Ismael's line and choosing the 0.8.18 compiler

Comment: @Gencho The contract has several logic errors that can only be fixed by the contract creator. It uses a couple variables `_pid`, `cost` without defining them.

Comment: try with this:
``return  string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, (tokenId+1).toString())) : "json";
``
But as Ismaeel mentioned some variables are not defined.